# copy java preferences file for specific java app

Tags: java, preferences

I run a java application like this:

```
java --cp libs.jar MyClass myconfigfile
```

After a normal shutdown, the app will remember the values I had in numerous text fields and checkboxes. I'm told that 'last state' is kept in java preferences. I want to grab my last state from one computer and bring it over to another. Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Write your 'last state` to a `file` or `in db`.

Comment: This is dependent on how your application is written. If the preferences are saved somewhere, there will likely be a file somewhere but you'll have to look for it. If it is in a file, you could try something like 'ls -Rlt' to list the files modified in your working directory and sub directories (ordered by timestamp).

Comment: The application itself is not saving the state. I was told that remembering those values is something java is doing via some preferences file or cache or something.

Comment: @allen that is definitely wrong. Java doesn't just remember the last application state magically by itself. There might be some frameworks but you have to actively program or include such a mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the limited information you provide, it sounds like the application is using the [Java Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).  In this case, where the data is actually stored is OS-dependent.  In Windows, it's in the Registry.  Linux and OS X, I'm not sure.  That is, the data is *not* likely stored in a single properties file somewhere from which you can just copy it.

If you have access to the code, you can export the Preferences object to a file though.

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("myPrefs.xml");
myPrefs.exportSubtree(output);
```

Edit: Looks like in Linux you may find the info in one of these two places:

```
~/.java/.userPrefs
/etc/.java/.systemPrefs
```

Comment: I had both .userPrefs and .systemPrefs folders, but only the .userPrefs location had the info I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regardless if your program is a class *or* a jar, one of the most portable methods is to just have a config file at the root of your project.

Example:

```
// Makes a file at the root of your project, and the name starts with a period so its hidden by the system.
File stateFile = new File(".lastState");
// Creates a file IF it doesn't exist already
stateFile.createNewFile();

// Do stuff

// Then save stuff to the file
```

Psuedo code for writing options:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(stateFile);

for(Option option : yourList.options()) {
    // Print the option name, a Unit seperator char, the status of the option, and a Group seperator char
    out.print(option.getName() + '\x1F' + option.status() + '\x1D');
}
```

Psuedo code for reading options:

```
private boolean readOptionsFromStateFile(Map<String, Option> mapOfOptionNamesToOption) {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(stateFile);
     in.setDelimiter("\\x1D"); // Set the delimiter to the group seperator
     while(in.hasNext()) {
         String temp = in.next();
         if(temp == "") return;
         String[] keyValues = temp.split("\x1F"); // Split at the unit seperator
         if(keyValues.length != 2) {
             return false;
         }
         Option curOption = mapOfOptionNamesToOption.get(keyValues[0]);
         if(curOption != null) {
             curOption.setStatus(keyValues[1]);
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     }
     return true;
}
```